# Can we find / express all matrices so that ${\bf P}^2 = {\bf P+I}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials, cayley-hamilton

> Can we find/express all matrices, so that:
>   $${\bf P}^2={\bf P+I}$$

**Own work:**

For the eigenvalues must then hold:

$$\lambda^2-\lambda-1=0$$
In other words : $$\lambda_1 = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2\\\lambda_2 = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$$

So as long as we construct a matrix with any combination of such eigenvalues, we shall be fine.

$${\bf P =SDS}^{-1},\\
 {\bf D} = \text{diag}(\text{AnyCombinationOf}\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\})$$
for any matrix $\bf S$.
For my experiments this does seem to give numerically reasonable results for lots of such generated $\bf P$ of sizes $2-6$. These numerical experiments do however not disprove that such matrices $\bf P$ could exist which do not fit this description.

---

Does this description or representation catch all possible such matrices, or do we miss some? How to prove?

Comment: If $S$ is invertible, don't see why $SDS^-1$ cannot be a "golden" matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every such matrix will fit that description.  In particular, if $P^2 - P - I = 0$, then the minimal polynomial of $P$ must divide $x^2 - x - 1 = (x - \lambda_1)(x - \lambda_2)$.  So, the minimal polynomial of $P$ has distinct (i.e. non-repeating) roots.  It follows that $P$ is indeed diagonalizable.

The only tricky fact here is that a matrix will be diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has non-repeating roots.  For a reference on that, confer chapter 3 of Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*.

For a more interesting proof, you can show that any vector $x$ can be decomposed into 
$$
x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}[(\lambda_2I - P)x - (\lambda_1 I - P)x].
$$
Argue that $(\lambda_1I - P)x, (\lambda_2 I - P)x$ are necessarily eigenvectors of $P$.